# 2 arrays into JSON

Tags: php, api, json

I have created an API to handle data requests from a MySQL database. The API is implemented in PHP.

I currently have a problem where I have a select query A and it returns a json object to the api caller:

```
<pre>
$queryA =  "SELECT ...";
$queryB = "SELECT ...";

      $a = array();
      if(mysqli_num_rows($queryAResult)) 
      {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryAResult))
        {   
            $a_a = $row["A"];
            $name = $row["name"];

            $arr = array('a' => $a_A, 'name' => $name);

            $a[] = array('a'=> $arr);
        }


              header('Content-type: application/json');
              echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode(array('a'=>$a)) . ');';
        }
</pre>
```

How do I json_encode and return 2 arrays please?

Comment: Merge in php and output as json? Not quite sure what you want here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply using an array of array

```
json_encode(array('a'=>$a,'b'=>$b))
```

What's your problem with that ?

```
$queryA =  "SELECT ...";
$queryB = "SELECT ...";

$a = array();
$b = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($queryAResult)) 
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryAResult))
    {   
        $a[] = array('a' => $row['A'],'name' => $row['name']);
    }

    if(mysqli_num_rows($queryBResult))
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryBResult))
        {   
            $b[] = array('b' => $row['B'],'name' => $row['name']);
        }

        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode(array('a'=>$a, 'b'=>$b)) . ');';
    }
}
```

Comment: is it that simple? Checking it out.